# I have a groovy script where I have value stored in a variable which I want to round off to 2 digit and return values

Tags: groovy, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

Code line:

```
def origEst = issue.getOriginalEstimate()
origEst = new Float(issue.getOriginalEstimate()/3600)

def origEstTotal = origEst.floatValue()

return origEstTotal
```

I want to round off `origEstTotal` to 2 digits if it has decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`round(int precision)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Float.html#round(int)):

```
def origEstTotal = new Float(123.00954)
def origEstTotalRounded = origEstTotal.floatValue().round(2)
println origEstTotalRounded
```

Prints

```
123.01
```